# Rails Seed Data not loading properly after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, seed

I loaded some seed data in using the code below, and it worked fine. Then, I needed to add two more columns, and I did so using the following steps, but it's not attaching the two new columns seed data to the table, what am I doing wrong?

Steps:

1. Add two columns using migration
2. Make them attr_accessible in the model
3. Replace old CSV file with new CSV file
4. Change the seed.rb file to plug in the new data
5. Run rake db:seed

Seed.rb

```
require 'csv'

Model.delete_all
CSV.foreach("#{Rails.root}/lib/data/model.csv") do |row|
   Model.create!(:model_number => row[0], :areq => row[1], :length => row[2], :width => row[3], :depth => row[4], :material => row[5], :frame => row[6], :edge => row[7], :tubes => row[8], :tube_length => row[9])
end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "models", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "model_number"
  t.float    "areq"
  t.float    "length"
  t.float    "width"
  t.float    "depth"
  t.string   "material"
  t.string   "frame"
  t.float    "edge"
  t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  t.float    "tubes"
  t.float    "tube_length"
end
```

Comment: Is the data getting saved at all and missing the new columns or is the whole row missing? Are your new attributes spelled right?

Comment: Yeah, the data is getting saved, it's just those two new columns that are missing. Does it have anything to do with the fact that the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' columns come before those two new ones? I tried changing their positions and it still didn't work though

Comment: No, that's normal. Have you tried running it in the console?

Comment: Can you post your relevant schema.rb info and the model.create(...) line?

Comment: Edited original post with the info

Comment: just a guess check if the proper model.csv is getting loaded and have column 8 and 9 means have in all 10 columns

Comment: I'd try walking through this in a console. and seeing what values row[8] and row[9] give you.

Comment: @PriteshJ Yeah it has 10 columns

Comment: Sorry, figured it out. Was placing the file in the wrong folder, stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant say this may work 100%

Try `Model.reset_column_information` above the seed file once

this should refresh the columns information in table.

```
require 'csv'

Model.reset_column_information

Model.delete_all
#......
```

just a guess check if the proper model.csv is getting loaded and have column 8 and 9 means have in all 10 columns.

Comment: can you add the  `desc` for that `models table` from `database` not the schema one, and also a `Model.new.inspect` from `rails console`

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but here is the code from using inspect: "#<Model id: nil, model_number: nil, areq: nil, length: nil, width: nil, depth: nil, material: nil, frame: nil, edge: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, tubes: nil, tube_length: nil>"

Comment: @user1486809, this looks good, try printing the values of row 8 and 9 and see if they are fetching data also check the datatype may  be the data is lost during conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually just made a stupid mistake and placed the file in the wrong folder

Comment: that what I suggested by asking are you loading the proper file , glad it worked :)

Comment: I have added this to the answer.